# Online C reference manuals

Tags: c, reference-manual

I've studied C programming in college some years ago and have developed some medium applications back then (nothing serious). Now I have to develop some more 'advanced' C applications (involving POSIX threads and RPC), but right now I'm a little rusty even with the basics.

Can anyone recommend me good online C reference manuals? This may help me get in tune faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- <del>[C standard library reference (both C89 and C99)](http://members.aol.com/wantondeb/)</del>
- [C89 library reference guide](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/)
- [GNU C tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/) (more than just a tutorial, quite a useful reference)

I got these all from a previous similar question on SO.  I would like to credit the original posters, but unfortunately cannot seem to find that question.

Comment: That first link is dead.

Comment: Second link died a while ago, too. :(

Answer (score 9):

For the very basic I found [this reference card](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~adnan/c-refcard.pdf) very useful.  Doesn't help with more advanced functions but it can help get the rust off.

Comment: It did help a lot as a quick reference while programming. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's not online, but hands down the best C reference is [Harbison & Steele](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X) (yeah - it's better than K&R).

You can get the 4th edition for basically shipping (I don't know what improvements were made in the 5th ed.):

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0133262243](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133262243)

Comment: Can you qualify "better" than K&R?

Comment: Well, it's just an opinion (and it's been a while since I've even looked at K&R), but it's comprehensive, clear, covers all the variants - pre-standard, standard, Unix, and even a bit of information on differences between C & C++.  From my recollection, K&R is more of a tutorial than a reference.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: The fifth edition can be found online [here](https://savedparadigms.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/harbison-s-p-steele-g-l-c-a-reference-manual-5th-ed.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget man pages. If you are developing on any UNIX-derived platform (Linux, BSD, Cygwin) you can almost always do something like `man printf` or `info printf` to get documentation for any library function.

Comment: Make sure you do `man 3 printf` - that one always trips me up.

Answer (score 2):

The best C reference by far is Kernighan and Ritchie's ["The C Programming Language"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) in it's dead tree form.  It's compact and complete.

For an online reference, you might try Brian Kernighan's [Programming in C Tutorial](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html).

Answer (score 2):

manuals

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bstk3k5.aspx

tutorial

- http://www.physics.drexel.edu/students/courses/Comp_Phys/General/C_basics/
- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html

Comment: The microsoft's link is for C++ not C!

Comment: This one looks like C.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw5abdx6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

the [C book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/) is freely available
on-line. It is not really a reference
manual, but still a pretty good
resource. From the website:

> This is the online version of The C
>   Book, second edition by Mike Banahan,
>   Declan Brady and Mark Doran,
>   originally published by Addison Wesley
>   in 1991. This version is made freely
>   available.
>
> While this book is no longer in print,
>   its content is still very relevant
>   today. The C language is still
>   popular, particularly for open source
>   software and embedded programming. We
>   hope this book will be useful, or at
>   least interesting, to people who use
>   C.

Answer (score 1):

The best online reference for C and C++ is probably www.cplusplus.com

QuantumPete

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading through the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) at least once to help get the rust off.  For reference material, you might want to grab a copy of the C Standard, the latest version of C99 with TC3 included is available for free [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), for C89 the last draft version is available as a [text file](http://www.cpax.org.uk/prg/portable/c/ansi_c.zip) or you can pick up a copy of the [The Annotated ANSI C Standard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0078819520) for a few bucks and have a hard copy of the actual standard (just ignore the "annotations" on the right-hand pages).  Since you are using POSIX you might want to become more familiar with the Single Unix Specification which includes the Standard C library as well as the POSIX functions, you can read/download SUSv3 at the [Open Group](http://www.unix.org/online.html) (registration required but free and quick).

For an offline resource I would also recommend [C: A Reference Manual (5th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X) by Harbison & Steele, it thoroughly covers every language feature and standard function of C and documents differences between the various standard versions.